# Edited JSON is saving with weird whitespace with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

So I have a PowerShell scripts, and it needs to edit and save JSON code for config files.

I load them in (there are three at the moment) using:

```
$cliConfig = Get-Content -Path $clientConfig | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Their properties are then manipulated in the array `$cliConfog` during the script. I then go to save it at the end of the script using

```
$cliConfig | ConvertTo-Json -depth | Out-File $clientConfig
```

You would think this would save as it comes in, but instead of saving like this

```
{
    "serverConfigVersion": 0,
    "dateUpdated": "01/01/2000",
    "errorStatus": false,
    "localClientVersion": 1.0,
    "ReleaseMain": [1.0, "01/01/2000", null],
    "BetaMain": [1.0, "01/01/2000", null],
    "ReleaseVersion": 1.0,
    "users": ["notLiam.Doyle", "Person2.Person", "Person3.Person"]
}
```

It saves like this;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBumO.png - for some reason it wont even let me paste it in. I think it's an encoding issue but I am unsure where. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the command line is more like this, without the -depth parameter with no value, and -append added to out-file:

```
$cliConfig | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -Append $clientConfig
```

Those spaces are probably nulls from mixing utf16 and utf8 encoding.  Don't append with out-file (same thing as >>), or use set-content or add-content instead.